# How add 20% to data synced to a different tab with QUERY with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to pull data from one google Sheets tab to another and add `20%` to the relevant cells.

The formula I am currently using is `=QUERY('Sheet 1'!G13:K1000)` to get the data into the second tab.

Can someone provide the formula i would need to add a calculation `*1.2` for `20%` ?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Keep in mind that we can't see what you see, and we don't know what is in your head. So identifying "the relevant cells" is meaningless at this point. We have no idea what fills your source range, which columns or areas are numbers, which you want the 20% added to, etc. Consider sharing a link to the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query formula-

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C5,"Select A, B, C*1.2 Label C*1.2 'Price w/ 20% markup', C*1.2'20%'",1)
```

[image]